# Ag-grid valueFormatter and Column Filter

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am having problems using ag-grid `valueFormatter` and column filters (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filtering/).

I have a simple colDef:

```
{
        headerName: 'My column',
        field: 'myData',
        hide: true,
        valueFormatter: this.formatterBooleanToHuman,
      },
```

the formatterBooleanToHuman is a simple code to change `true` to Yes and `false` to No.

It works as expected, the issue is that we are using column filters, and when I click on the filter I have `true` and `false` to select, if I select any of them, nothing returns from the filters because the value now is actually Yes and No.

I couldn't manage to have both of them working together. To have the column filter working properly I need to remove the valueFormatter, but I would like to have both working.

I tried to apply the valueFormatter function to filterParams.valueFormatter, it did change the values on the filter but something is failing, I am getting 2 No and 1 Yes, and none of them filter.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

So, I found a solution, but I am not convinced it is the right way to do it.

```
get getcolumnDef(): Array<ColDef> {
  return [
      {
        headerName: 'Boolean Column',
        field: 'booleanValue',
        hide: true,
        valueFormatter: this.formatterBooleanToHuman,
        filterParams: {
          valueGetter: (params) => this.filterBooleanValueGetter(params, 'booleanValue')
        }
      }
    ];
  }
        
  private filterBooleanValueGetter(params: ValueGetterParams, propertyName: string) {
    let isDeleted = false;

    const hasValue = !!params && !!params.data && params.data[propertyName];

    if (hasValue) {
      isDeleted = String(params.data[propertyName]) === 'true';
    }

    return isDeleted ? 'Yes' : 'No';
  }
```

So, the `valueGetter` works as expected and makes my filter work, I just think it is a bit "dirty" to have it to work like that, I haven't found anything on the docs saying this is the way it needs to be done. So suggestions are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

`valueFormatter` applies only to data in grid. However even if the filter shows `true` and `false` instead of formatted values, it should work correctly. If filtering does not work, it may indicate some other error in your code. Maybe you depend on `this` in `formatterBooleanToHuman` method?

Anyway to format values in filter, you should define `filterParams.valueFormatter` like this:

```
{
  // ...
  valueFormatter: this.formatterBooleanToHuman,
  filterParams: {
    valueFormatter: this.formatterBooleanToHuman
  }
}
```

For some reason, the value given to filter formatter is `string` instead of `boolean` (bug in ag-grid?), you need to adjust that.

See complete example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/o3sN3GodqQumVe09

Answer (score 0):

Using `valueGetter` worked for me instead of valueFormatter. [ValueGetter Doc](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/value-getters/)

```
{
 valueGetter: this.getDataValue
}
```